# In Ruby language, how to post data to a web page that need authentication?

Tags: ruby, http, network-programming

I use `e-texteditor` as my primary editor, in which you can execute dynamic languages directly, such as `Ruby, Python, Perl` etc. Now I want to write blog post in this editor and post it to my blog directly. Though, the blog need authentication(username and password). How can I post data to this kinda of pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). It emulates a real broswer, and is quite powerful. About the only major feature lacking is a javascript engine, so it won't work if the blog uses javascript in its authentication.